# Divide and Conquer

Tags: math, optimization, computer-science, mathematical-optimization, divide-and-conquer

Been learning about Divide and Conquer and I am struggling to understand one concept. If we have a sorted array and want to do some task.... we get the formula

```
T(n) = a (n/b) * O(n)
```

And if we use `b = 2` (binary tree) , meaning each subarray is made into two more subarrays... we get

`T(n) = 2 (n/2) * O(n)` --> and by master rule the `running time = O(n * logn)`

Now if we use `b = 3` (tri-nary tree) , meaning each subarray is made into three more subarrays we get

`T(n) = 3 (n/3) * O(n)` --> which means that `running time = O(n * logn)`

**QUESTION:**

Should the running time be longer if we make more splits?

why do I keep getting the same running time no matter how big my tree is?

Comment: I think you mean `a (n/b) + O(n)` (PLUS, not *)

Comment: what do you mean PLUS not *

Comment: Recurrences are badly writen. I guess that their correct intended versions are: `T(n)=aT(n/b)+O(n)`, `T(n)=2T(n/2)+O(n)` and `T(n)=3T(n/3)+O(n)`.

Comment: This question is off-topic. It fits much better in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. You have a length `n` array. At each level of the tree you subdivide that array. But in total there are still `n` elements, no matter how you subdivide it.

At the parent level you do `n` work. At each child you do `n/X` work, but you do it `X` times, so again it's `n` work.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Whatever the degree of the tree, Sum of next level process is same. As you know, the degree of the tree is bigger, the process at child node is smaller. And Sum of next level Process is same. But it is only valid with idle condition. In practical, Because of recursive function call, more degree of tree has slower run time than less degree of tree.